# How to integrate azure ad with spring boot using non organizational account?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to integrate azure ad with spring boot.
Created one personal account on azure :
myName@outlook.com.

But it is not allowing me to add users under azure active directory, hence unable to integrate with sprint boot.

Can we integrate with spring boot using personal accounts on azure, which are not organizational account.

Comment: Personal accounts can sign in to your app if you set the app registration to support personal accounts as well, and use the "common" or "consumers" endpoint instead of "organizations" or a specific tenant ID.

Comment: okay can you help with an example on what you are saying to do

Answer (score 0):

> **Note** that: You must have organizational account to integrate Azure AD with Spring Boot. By creating an Azure subscription, you can get an organizational account.

- You can create an Azure AD tenant and add users to it if you have an Azure subscription.
- The Azure AD tenancy can then be used by Spring Boot application to authenticate users.

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment like below:***

When I logged in with personal account, the **`Create new user`** option is greyed out:

[image]

When I logged in with **organization account with subscription**, I am able to create users like below:

[image]

If you want users (*personal accounts/organization accounts/Any*) to sign-in to the Application, check the below:

Create an Azure AD Application:

[image]

Then use **`common`** endpoint to authorize users like below:

For sample:

```json
https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize? 

client_id=ClientID
&response_type=code  
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=query  
&scope=https://graph.microsoft.com/.default
&state=12345
```

[image]

***The user got signed in successfully like below:***

[image]